# What does a tilde in angle brackets mean when creating a Java generic class?

Tags: java, generics, intellij-idea, syntax, tilde

I was reading through some JMockit examples and found this code:

```
final List<OrderItem> actualItems = new ArrayList<~>();
```

What does the tilde in the generic identifier mean? I know it's the unary bitwise NOT operator, but I don't see an operand here.

Also, I tried compiling it and got an error. Am I just missing something?

Answer (score 178, accepted):

> It is just a shorthand for "same as in declaration".

Some IDEs, e.g. IntelliJ use this too.

The files on disk do not have this notation, which is only a compaction in the IDE GUI.

Comment: It was an Intellij screenshot.

Comment: Just for personal clarification - IntelliJ produces Java source files with *this* notation, iaw, source files with illegal Java content??? Or is this just the *view* of the source and the saved file is correct?

Comment: @Andreas_D: It is just a view. The files on disk are ok.

Comment: And actually, the tilde is grayed (to indicate that it's different), and if you click on it, it'll expand to the full definition.

Comment: This can be disabled in the intelij settings for editor/general/Code Folding.

Answer (score 20):

If there wasn't a tilde, I'd say, the code was already Java 7. [Java 7 allows the diamond operator](http://code.joejag.com/2009/new-language-features-in-java-7/) so this is/will be legal Java code:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

(but - no tilde with this syntax)

Answer (score 15):

In IntelliJ IDEA, the `~` here:

```
Set<String> associations = new LinkedHashSet<~>();
```

means `String`, which is the same as in the declaration on the left side.

Answer (score 2):

I think that is shorthand to mean whatever the type is, in this case *OrderItem*.