# What does <~> in Java mean?

Tags: java

Tried to google it but not sure how to phrase it! Tilde in between angular brackets?! Did not return anything..I know < T > is a generic, not sure what generic a tilde represents.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887876/what-does-this-tilde-mean

Comment: Ah alright thanks. Didn't land at that page however much I searched!